# Generating ethereum address from private key on Ubuntu 32 bit

Tags: security, private-key, cold-storage

I have a securely generated private key that I want to use to generate an ethereum address on an offline PC (Ubuntu 32 bit). My preferred way would be to use geth, but there's no geth binary for linux 32 bit. My questions are:

Why there are no 32-bit binaries available?
What are the alternative ways to generate an ethereum address (binaries preferred) except MyEtherWallet?
What happens if I try to run 64-bit geth on 32-bit Linux?

Comment: I got a 64-bit PC so I hope geth binary will solve my problem. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively if you are happy installing node.js and npm, you can choose from multiple Javascript projects handling keys:

- [ethereumjs-wallet](https://github.com/axic/ethereumjs-wallet) or [keythereum](https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum) if you want to code a bit or
- [helpeth](https://github.com/ethereumjs/helpeth) if you need a simple commandline tool.

This command should give you the details needed:

```
$ helpeth -p <your private key as a hex string> keyDetails
```

Make sure to double check the output, that it matches your input private key!

```
$ ./helpeth -p 0x71a7f0e2ef1b7ff501b65a1650d48b8d5521fadc9539eec146d4faa6f5ca9aca --show-private keyDetails
Address: 0x15f2f3e0f2d74ea7b185fc12f24cb4f402cc96d0
Address (checksum): 0x15F2f3e0F2D74eA7B185fC12F24cB4F402cC96D0
ICAP: XE53 2KAS Y050 UIFI VB1J 2636 IKXC 4QIP SK0
Public key: 0xf2a3a694026ed4abb16e18f0421a6e667803399dad2eae2ca8c3f95934fcb46e9440183fd278181deb501d2f0766d0f676d0cac84da3632590e2978cb6883bc4
Private key: 0x71a7f0e2ef1b7ff501b65a1650d48b8d5521fadc9539eec146d4faa6f5ca9aca
```

Note, if you are happy installing a browser you can use a local copy of  EtherAddress (https://ryepdx.github.io/ethaddress.org/) or EtherWallet - both run in-browser, you don't need Internet connection for them.

Answer (score 3):

Since `geth` is not available, use `eth` as client. You can build it from source, [following these instructions](https://ethereum-homestead.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/building-from-source/linux.html):

```
git clone https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella
cd webthree-umbrella
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make -j $(nproc)
```

Or simply [install it from the repositories](https://ethereum-homestead.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/installing-binaries/linux-ubuntu-ppa.html):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ethereum/ethereum-qt
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cpp-ethereum eth ethkey
```

Import your plain private key with `ethkey`:

```
ethkey importbare 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

This account will be available in your `eth` client.

Comment: Building eth takes way longer than geth, so if you're building from source, you might as well just build geth